# Number Theory:Quadratic Reciprocity Part II

Tags: number-theory

Claim: If $p \equiv 2 \mod 5$ then $5$ is a non-residue modulo $p$.

Attempt: I know that similarly to proving Quadratic Reciprocity Part II, we need to reduce the numbers $5,10,15,\cdots,\frac{5}{2}(p−1)$ so that they lie between $-\frac{1}{2}(p-1)$ and $\frac{1}{2}(p-1)$ and see how many of them are negative but I don't know how that proves the claim.

Comment: I like this direct approach, which doesn't rely on Quadratic Reciprocity. Note that you get positives for a while, then negatives, then positives, then negatives, then positives. Find the break points in terms of p and count the elements in each part. Fun counting exercise (and not too hard -- you just need to be careful).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for $\left( \dfrac{5}{p} \right)$, but we understand only $\left( \dfrac{p}{5}\right)$. In particular, the squares mod $5$ are $1$ and $4$, so $\left( \dfrac{p}{5} \right) = -1$ and $p$ is not a square mod $5$. How do we relate this to $\left( \dfrac{5}{p} \right)$?

We use what you mentioned: the law of quadratic reciprocity! Since $5 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, we know that $\left( \dfrac{5}{p} \right)=\left( \dfrac{p}{5} \right)$, and so $5$ is not a square mod $p$. $\diamondsuit$